# What is the best ruby practice for batch inserting into the database when you’re in a loop that is creating new DB entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, data-entry

In ruby, if I have a loop generating .new database entries and adding them into an array. I currently .import after the loop is completed. However, I was wondering if I can import while the loop is running. (I.e. after 1K of new entries are added to the array then import it to the database and reset the array? Is there a best practice for this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Solutions vary based on requirements. For example, do you want to run ActiveRecord validations or can they be skipped? How many total records? If you can skip validations and you have millions of records, for example, you'd probably use [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) or your RDBMS' equivalent.

Comment: did you use any import gem ?

Comment: Sounds like a job for multi-insert or a prepared statement you can recycle as necessary.

Comment: You can use this gem 'Activerecord-Import' which can be used to import in batch, I think instead of controlling over array you can import in batch.

Comment: There are several ways of doing it, depending on your use case and version of Rails. Here is some info: https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/11/26/rails-6-insert-all.html